# UIButton : CATransition unpredictable behaviour

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, cocos2d-iphone

I am developing a game using cocos2D and I am shifting from my home view which is a viewController class to gameScene. I am using UIButtons in home screen and I am using `CATransition` animation to reveal the buttons when the view appears. I am not releasing the home view when the game scene is loaded. The home view is present behind the game scene. And when the game scene ends, i hide the game scene and displays the home scene.

This the code of creating the button :

```
// Play Button
btnPlay = [[UIButton alloc]init];
btnPlay.frame = CGRectMake(65,95,124,50);
[btnPlay addTarget:self action:@selector(btnPlayAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[btnPlay setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[btnPlay setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnPlay setHidden:YES];
btnPlay.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"NoteWorthy" size:25.0f];
[btnPlay setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:btnPlay];
[btnPlay setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
```

This the code for `CATransition` of button :

```
CATransition *animation3 = [CATransition animation];
[animation3 setDuration:3.0f];
[animation3 setType:kCATransitionReveal];
[animation3 setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
[[btnPlay layer] addAnimation:animation3 forKey:@"SwitchToView"];

[btnPlay setHidden:NO];
```

For few replays the transition goes well. But after few more replays of game, sometimes `kCATransitionReveal` happens and sometimes kCATransitionFromLeft happens. But I have not used `kCATransitionFromLeft` in my code. How it is happening?

Thanks for the help.